# Contacts framework does not seem to be available for iPad Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the iPad Swift Playgrounds app to learn Swift.  I tried to work with the Contacts framework to do things such as add a contact.  When I try to import the Contacts framework by using the statement "import Contacts", I am told that the module does not exist.  Is there anything I can do to make this framework available?

I searched Google for sample code and the sample code I have found requires this module.

```
import Contacts
```

will display:

> No such module 'Contacts'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, not every Apple-provided framework is available in Swift Playgrounds for iPad. Contacts is one of those not included.

To use the framework, you'll need to use Xcode or Swift Playgrounds on a Mac. Although `import Contacts` does work on a Mac, it won't work on an iPad, as it does not include the framework.

Comment: Swift Playgrounds for macOS seems to have the same error as iPad.

Answer (score 0):

This module appears to be available on Swift Playgrounds for iOS (I am using 3.4 (1302.27). <- use settings to find version string

The error does not occur anymore.

Comment: Also, I used the sample code in Contacts and it will create a "Johnny Appleseed" contact on iPad via Playgrounds, but not macOS.